# Java Exception Handling for Scanner input: Clearing bad data with nextLine (catch vs Finally)

Tags: java, exception, buffer, java.util.scanner, inputstream

When you call input.nextLine() as part of your exception catching is it better to place it into every catch block or just inside a finally block at the end of the try-catch. What is the advantage or disadvantage to either approach?

example:

```
catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Cannot add to Database, please enter only integers");
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Impossible to add, please enter only letters from a-z");
    }
```

Or

```
catch (InputMismatchException e)
    {

        System.out.println("Cannot add to Database, please enter only integers");
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        System.out.println("Impossible to add, please enter only letters from a-z");
    }

    finally
    {
        input.nextLine();
    }
```

What is the advantage or disadvantage to either approach?

Regards,

Pill.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read next line irrespective of exception conditions(exception raised or not raised whether it is handled or not handled) write `input.nextLine()` in `finally` block. If you want to read next line only when an exceptions raised and it is handled then write `input.nextLine()` in respective `catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

`catch` and `finally` are different usage. 
`finally` don't care about exception types, etc. So, use `finally` when you need to execute code whether the method process ok or not.

`catch` care about exception types. So, you handle when exceptoin occured. Because you don't want your application crash.